# Using a PHP variable as a form fields default value

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a created an HTML form where users sign up and input there data into an SQL database. I have then retrieved that data in a webpage where they can view their profile. I have created a page where users can edit there profile by creating a form which updates the value in the SQL database for there user id.

I would like the form to use the current value of the SQL cell as the default for that user to make alterations easier. Example: currently user 7 has their city set as New York, when they visits the edit info page, the city field in the form already hase New York as the default value.

I have no problem getting the SQL info and assigning it to a variable, I just don't understand how to set it as the default value. I am aware of how you set default values for input fields though.

My code:

```
<?php
$id = $_SESSION["user_id"];    

// Create a query for the database
$query = "SELECT full_name FROM users WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1";

// Get a response from the database by sending the connection
// and the query
$response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

// If the query executed properly proceed
if($response){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
echo $row['full_name'];   
echo mysqli_error();    
}
}
?>  
<input type="text" name="aboutme" defualt="<?php echo $row['aboutme'] ?>" >
```

Comment: Plz post what code you already have.

Comment: `<input ... value="<?php echo $yourvalue ?>">`1

Comment: So… your problem is that you don't know how to print a variable to the page?

Comment: @MarcB — htmlspecialchars! Don't open the system up to stored XSS attacks.

Comment: Is the issue related to setting default html input variables?

Comment: I have added my code to the question, my problem is that the php variable is not being shown as the default. I know that I have set the variable properly as it is shown by the echo in the main bulk of the code, however when I try to call the variable again to set as the default, it is not shown.

Answer (score 3):

There's no `default` value for html input.
Input can has value, using attribute `value`:

```
<input type="text" name="some_name" value="Some value" />
```

In your case it's

```
<input type="text" name="aboutme" value="<?php echo $row['aboutme']?> />
```

Input can also has `placeholder` - some value that is present in an input, but erased when user starts to edit input's content:

```
<input type="text" name="aboutme" value="<?php echo $row['aboutme']?> placeholder="some value" />
```

Comment: I tried using the code, and there was an error as it was missing a speech mark, after adding the speech mark the field was still blank when the page loaded. The code I used was: `<input type="text" name="aboutme" value="<?php echo $row['aboutme']?>"/>`

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
<?php
$id = $_SESSION["user_id"];    

// Create a query for the database
$query = "SELECT full_name FROM users WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1";

// Get a response from the database by sending the connection
// and the query
$response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

// If the query executed properly proceed
if($response){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
echo $row['full_name'];   
?>
<input type="text" name="aboutme" value="<?php echo $row['aboutme'] ?>" > 
<?php
echo mysqli_error();    
}
}
?>
```

And here is a good example `http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphpfile.asp?filename=demo_db_select_pdo`

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the answers worked and upon further research and trial and error I created a solution.

I changed the value that was store in the array to just be a normal php variable:

```
$aboutme = $row['aboutme'];
```

I then called that variable using the following code:

```
<input type="text" name="aboutme" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($aboutme); ?>" >
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you find my answer useful.

Why don't you try using it as a place holder? This will provide editable text.

```
<input type="text" name="aboutme" placeholder="<?php echo $row['aboutme'];" />
```

Comment: Actually, the placeholder attribute just displays "gray suggested text" that you cannot edit.

Comment: OH yes, you're right.